# Copying a string in x86 assembly using indirect addressing

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am still very new to assembly and only tonight have started to even begin to understand the majority of what I'd like to do so I may have many things wrong but it is hard for me to tell where due to lack of experience.

I am attempting to copy a string from source to target using indirect addressing in x86 assembly. I am trying to apply the understanding I have from this explanation but am struggling to understand how exactly to copy the data @ esi into edi.

```
.data
val1 BYTE 10h,20h,30h
.code
mov esi,OFFSET val1
mov al,[esi]    ; dereference ESI (AL = 10h)

inc esi
mov al,[esi]    ; AL = 20h

inc esi
mov al,[esi]    ; AL = 30h
```

This is what I've done so far and I've actually gotten it to run (!!!) but unfortunately it does not copy at all. I suspect that my loop is bad (I'm not sure exactly how to exit it properly) and there is something crazy going on with my copying but I do not know where I am going wrong:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
   source  BYTE  "Source string I want to copy",0
   target  BYTE  SIZEOF source DUP(0)

.code
main PROC
    mov  esi,OFFSET source              
    mov  edi,OFFSET target             
L1:
    mov  al,[esi]       ; get char from source
    mov  [edi],al       ; store it in target
    inc  esi            ;move to next char in source
    inc  edi            ;move to next position in target
    cmp al, 28          ;compare al to 28 (the number of chars in source string)
    JNZ L1              ;repeat the loop if al != 28 (length of source string)

    mov edx, OFFSET source 
    call WriteString ;Prints out source string (working fine)
    mov edx, OFFSET target
    call WriteString ;Prints out dest string (working fine)
```

The writestrings are working properly at the bottom because I was able to get it to output "Source string I want to copySource string I want to copy" into the console when running using indexed addressing.

Comment: you should compare al with 28, not esi. and your source string should end with a "#" then

Comment: of course it does, your source string is not terminated by "'#" ;-)

Comment: I've never seen this before and am unsure where this is supposed to go / why. Could you explain what this does and where exactly it goes? I have tried within the quotations of the string, just outside, and just after 0 and it still keeps crashing. Google / stackoverflow searching doesn't show much about strings ending with "#".

Comment: @Tommylee2k: I don't think the `#` in the comment refers to the character `'#'`, but rather to the word "number", as in "the number of chars" (which happens to be 28).

Comment: ah, I see. that's what happens when I read what I want to read, not what's written. So the original problem was, that he compared SI with 28, not with "offset target + 28", which would've fixed the problem. Using the terminating 0 instead still is the better way to solve it, you're right with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string is NUL-terminated (the `,0` at the end of the string). So forget about comparing against some hardcoded length that you'll have to change if you modify the string; just check if the byte you read is zero instead:

```
L1:
    mov  al,[esi]       
    mov  [edi],al       
    inc  esi            
    inc  edi            
    test al,al          ; you could also use  cmp al,0  if you prefer that
    JNZ L1              ; repeat the loop if al != 0
```

Comment: Yes! This was so simple and helped a ton! This was my first time using cmp/test and I had the general idea but didn't execute it 100% correctly. Thanks so much for the explanation. My only previous experience with loops in assembly was with a loop counter using indexed addressing so this was a good learning experience :)